# Barcode scanning performance of expo-camera vs expo-barcode-scanner

Tags: expo, barcode-scanner

Has anyone compared the barcode scanning performance (scan speed, battery usage) of the expo-camera vs. expo-barcode-scanner library? It appears they use different external libraries for the barcode detection.